# JPA Fetch Types

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two model classed called users and authorities. I used fetch type EAGER so that all the data even the ones from the authorities tables would be fetched as they are mapped to each other, But for some reason it is not fetching the details from the authorities table.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users",
            cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            targetEntity = Authorities.class)
    private Set<Authorities> authorities;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
public class Authorities {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String role;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Users.class,
            cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "authorities")
    private Users users;

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {

    Optional<Users> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

This method findByEmail is not fetching all the details from the database. It is only fetching the data from the users table but not from the authorities table even though i am using fetch type EAGER.

Comment: you can also try `user.getAuthorities()` manually so that it will load the authorities. It will solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Spring Data ignores fetch types and fetch mode. You can use Entity Graphs. See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "authorities.detail",  attributeNodes = NamedAttributeNode("authorities"))
public class Users {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  @Column(unique = true)
  private String email;
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private String password;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users",
        cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        targetEntity = Authorities.class)
  private Set<Authorities> authorities;
```

}

Comment: I tried using entity graphs but for some reason its still not working.

Comment: This is what i did.
```
@EntityGraph(value = "authorities.detail", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    Optional<Users> findByEmail(String email);
```
and i also added @NamedEntityGraph(name = "authorities.detail",  attributeNodes = NamedAttributeNode("authorities"))
public class Users {

Comment: @Entity graphs is working but for some reason the value is not getting stored in the Users Object. This is the output of the sql which was generated.

Comment: **select users0_.id as id1_1_0_, authoritie1_.id as id1_0_1_, users0_.email as email2_1_0_, users0_.firstname as firstnam3_1_0_, users0_.lastname as lastname4_1_0_, users0_.password as password5_1_0_, authoritie1_.role as role2_0_1_, authoritie1_.users_id as users_id3_0_1_, authoritie1_.users_id as users_id3_0_0__, authoritie1_.id as id1_0_0__ from users users0_ left outer join authorities authoritie1_ on users0_.id=authoritie1_.users_id where users0_.email=?**